# Will a MySql trigger occur before a PDO result is returned?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, triggers

Given an AFTER INSERT trigger on a mysql database table and a PDO insert record call.  Will the trigger happen before the return result of the insert statement or will it occur asynchronously?  Will it hold up the return result if the trigger takes forever to execute?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: given that a trigger can abort an in-progress query it has to happen BEFORE any results can be returned to php.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it would vary between versions.  I am on 5.1.69.  Also, I didn't know that an after trigger could abort a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will happen **before** `PDO::query` is returning or better spoken, before the mysql server is responding to the client request. This is necessary to keep data health.

The best test to proof this is to put an error into the trigger code and see the error happen in php.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL documentation,
An error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.

So, your query will return the result once the trigger finishes its execution or will return the error.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html